# Can a function literal use type parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala

Given the following definition of a method `removeAt` that's polymorphic:

```
def removeAt[T](n: Int, ts: Seq[T]): (Seq[T], T) = ???
```

How can I declare a list of `removeAt`-like functions? Can a function literal use type parameter?

How can I make the following compilable and able to contain `removeAt`?

```
List[(Int, Seq[_]) => (Seq[_], _)](removeAt)
```

UPDATE: Why does the following work fine so I can `foreach` over the list and execute the functions? That's exactly what I needed in the first place.

```
val solutions = Seq[(Int, Seq[Any]) => (Seq[Any], Any)](
  removeAt
)
```

Comment: This is possible in Scala 3 https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/polymorphic-function-types.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The blog post [First-class polymorphic function values in shapeless (1 of 3) — Function values in Scala](http://www.chuusai.com/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/) seems to imply that there's no way in "standard" Scala to have polymorphic function values:

> We can have first-class monomorphic function values and we can have
>   second-class polymorphic methods, but we can't have first-class
>   polymorphic function values ... at least we can't with the standard
>   Scala definitions.

It looks like we need a library like [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

Comment: Yes, shapeless is a good idea for type-level programming. So anyway, to have a list of functions, and not to loose their types, you have to use a heterogeneous list.

Comment: @DaunnC, could you comment on `you have to use a heterogeneous list`? I'd like to use the trick if that would be of any help in this case.

Comment: I tried to write a little, has no lots of time now, and I am not sure, that completely recognized your question.

Comment: Thanks @DaunnC. I need a solution to "list" methods I should put under test later. Test should be generic and hence the need for a solution with Seq so I `foreach` over it and execute the methods, and the object with methods under test be modified by users who offer their implementations (beside the others in the object).

Comment: so if the problem of storing methods decided, now, you need to go through list? You can go through `HList` using `map`, and apply each function to some object. Or you need to store functions in a `Seq`?

Answer (score 0):

Good enough to make the container carry these functions would be to use bottom types for example:

```
val f = removeAt _ 

var l: List[(Int, Seq[Nothing]) => (Seq[Nothing], Nothing)] = Nil
l = f :: l
```

I've explained them in this article for example: http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#the-bottom-types-nothing-and-null

Comment: Thanks, but after eta-expansion the function is...unusable and won't make itself any good for use. The type can only be Nothing that doesn't give much.

Answer (score 0):

You might be asking something more general than this, but for the above problem I feel like you're just approaching it wrong. If I were you, I'd extend `Seq` to support the `removeAt` method using an *implicit [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)*. Here's an example that would add the `removeAt` method:

```
implicit class MoreSeqOps[T](val seq: Seq[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def removeAt(n: Int): (Seq[T], T) = {
    val (xs, ys) = seq.splitAt(n)
    return (xs ++ ys.tail, ys.head)
  }
}
```

By using a *value class*, you avoid the extra overhead associated with creating a wrapper instance. Here's a sample usage from the REPL:

```
scala> (1 to 10) removeAt 3
res7: (Seq[Int], Int) = (Vector(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),4)
```

Comment: Thanks @DaoWen. I'm not looking for `implicit`s to add a method to an existing class, but rather collect (in a `List`) all the methods that should then be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we have a polymorphic function (only example to try and to compile, using shapeless):

```
def removeAt[T](n: Int, ts: Seq[T]): (Seq[T], T) = ...
```

Let's define a `HList` of these functions:

```
val mapList = 
    removeAt[Int] _     ::
    removeAt[String] _  ::
    removeAt[Boolean] _ :: HNil
```

So it is possible, to take any of these functions and to apply it.

Due to your example after update: In fact, you lose all information about polymorphic function types (due to type erasure). All functions in your list gonna have `(Int, Seq[Any]) => (Seq[Any], Any)` type, it is not good, as I recognize.

So with common lists, you can make the same (you should write type parameter), but also, you will lose all inforamtion about functions type, and in fact it is pointless to make such list or seq.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
val removeAt: Int => Seq[_] => (Seq[_], _) = n => seq => (seq, seq(n))

val listOfRemoveFun = List[(Int => Seq[_] => (Seq[_], _))](removeAt)

listOfRemoveFun.foreach(fun => println(fun(1)(Seq(1,2,3))))   //(List(1, 2, 3),2)
```