# Define parametrized function type

Tags: scala

I would like to define a new type for parametrized functions that adhere to some constraints. Something like:

```
import scala.util.Try
type Bound = Any

trait T1 {
  def apply[A <: Bound](a: A): Try[A]
}
```

This works but the only way to define a function of type `T1` is e.g.

```
val t1: T1 = new T1 {
    override def apply[A](a: A): Try[A] = Try(a)
}
```

which is a bit cumbersome. A more appropriate way to write something like that would make use of function literals.

Is there a way around it?

Keep in mind that defining the type like this:

```
trait T2[A <: Bound] extends (A => Try[A])
```

will not work because every instance of that type would have to define the type parameter, sacrificing the `genericness` of defined instance.

```
val t: T2[Int] = (a: Int) => Success(a)
```

Comment: Use scala 2.12 with [SAM types](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types)

Comment: @MuratMustafin Won't work, I need the result to be generic

Comment: How would you like the use to look like, given function literals cannot be generic?

Comment: This question is a bit similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294264/can-a-function-literal-use-type-parameter-in-scala

Comment: No, there isn't (at least so far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

*(untested, just an idea that might work)*

I'm not aware of a concise syntax for that in Scala.

However, if you are willing to generalize `T1` a little bit, then there are plugins which attempt to solve a slightly more general version of your problem.

What you are asking is essentially: "Is there inline-syntax for natural transformations":

```
trait T1[F[_], G[_]] {
  def apply[A <: UpperBound](x: F[A]): G[A]
}
```

In your case, `F` is `Id`, and `G` is `Try`, and additionally, you have a constraint on `A`. This pattern is rather common, and so for example [here](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/arrow/FunctionK.html) you are advised to use the non/kind-projector compiler plugin for exactly such cases. This would allow you to write this:

```
val t1 = λ[T1[Id, Try]](bodyOfTheApplyMethod)
```

In the [documentation of non/kind-projector compiler plugin](https://github.com/non/kind-projector#polymorphic-lambda-values), there are several requirements listed for this to work. In particular, `T1` really needs to be parameterized by two type constructors `F` and `G`. Moreover, I'm not sure whether it is clever enough to insert the type bound at the right place during the rewriting.

---

That being said, I'd just go with

```
val t1 = new T1 { 
  def apply[X <: Bound](x: X): Try[X] = body 
}
```

I think to solve your concrete problem in an optimal way, you would have to modify the non/kind-projector plugin. Or wait for some future version of dotty. Or switch to a language with dependent types, where there is no big difference between type parameters and ordinary parameters.

Or just accept it as is and use `new ... { def ... }`-syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, using a companion object:

```
import scala.util.{Success, Try}
type Bound = Any

trait T1[A <: Bound] {
  def apply(a: A): Try[A]
}

object T1 {
  def apply[A <: Bound](f: A => Try[A]) = {
    new T1[A] {
      override def apply(a: A): Try[A] = f(a)
    }
  }
}

val t1 = T1( (a: Int) => Success(a) )
```

However I am afraid it does exactly the same as the solution with `trait T2[A <: Bound]` you specifically do not want to use - the function created this way is no longer generic.

I am afraid the approach with generic `apply` member of `T1` is doomed to fail, because with that interface you promise to provide a generic function. There is no way to satisfy this promise with a literal, and Scala 2.12 SAM does not change this.

Comment: Unfortunately I need the result function to be generic.